# Monotonic increasing smooth function such that $f(0) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = C$ with $C < \infty$

Tags: examples-counterexamples, smooth-functions

I'm looking for examples of smooth functions $f \colon \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ such that

- $f(0) = 0$
- $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = C$ with $0 < C < \infty$
- $f$ is monotonic increasing

A clear example is
$$
f(x) = C\left(1-\exp(-(x / \lambda)^\beta)\right)
$$
The CDF of a Weibull random variable with scale parameter $\lambda > 0$ and shape parameter $\beta > 0$.

What are other examples?

Comment: Try a scaled version of $\arctan x$. Also $\tanh x$ comes to mind.

Comment: $f(x) = C \tanh(x)$ restricted to positives is already satisfying all criteria!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some examples:

1. $\frac{2C}\pi \arctan ax$ for any $a>0$.
2. $C\tanh ax$ for any $a>0$.
3. $\frac{Cx}{1+x}$
4. $1-\exp(-x)$, and appropriate scaled versions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by taking $g(x)=C\cdot f(x)$ with $f(x)$ a [smooth transition function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Smooth_transition_functions) you will achieve what you want to do, as [example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Piecewise%5B%7B%7B0%2C+x%3C%3D0%7D%2C%7B1+%2Cx%3E%3D1%7D%2C+%7B1%2F%281%2Be%5E%28%282x-1%29%2F%28x%5E2-x%29%29%29%2C+0%3C+x%3C1%7D%7D%5D&lang=es):
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,\quad x\leq 0, \\
1,\quad x\geq 1, \\
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x}\right)},\ 0<x< 1
\end{cases}$$

these kind of functions are smooth $f(x)\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and they achieve a constant value in a finite interval, having a constant value outside, which makes them non-analytic smooth functions.